# Using Eigen to Solve Linear Equations Modulo 2

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to use Eigen to solve equations over [GF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)) (i.e., modulo 2).

Unfortunately, I am getting incorrect results for some 5x5 matrices (smaller matrices seem to work).

Here is my code, including an example which demonstrates the incorrect behavior:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>   // assert
#include <stdexcept>  // std::invalid_argument

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <iostream>

//////////
// GF 2 //
//////////

/**
 * Enable solving modulo 2, inspired by
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747377/custom-scalar-type-in-eigen
**/

struct GF2 {
   public:
    bool value;
    GF2() : value(0) {};
    GF2(bool v) : value(v) {};

    GF2 operator-() const { return *this; };

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const GF2 &val) {
        out << val.value << " ";
        return out;
    }

    GF2 &operator+=(const GF2 &rhs) {
        this->value ^= rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }

    GF2 &operator-=(const GF2 &rhs) {
        return *this += rhs;
    }

    GF2 &operator*=(const GF2 &rhs) {
        this->value &= rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }

    GF2 &operator/=(const GF2 &rhs) {
        if (rhs.value == 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Division by zero");
        }
        return *this;
    }

    GF2 operator/(int rhs) {
        if (rhs == 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Division by zero");
        }
        return GF2(this->value);
    }

    operator bool() const {
        return value;
    }

};

bool isfinite(const GF2 &) { return true; }

namespace Eigen {
    template <>
    struct NumTraits<GF2> : NumTraits<bool> {
    // https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1NumTraits.html
        enum {
            IsComplex = 0,
            IsInteger = 0,
            IsSigned = 0,
            RequireInitialization = 1,
            ReadCost = 1,
            AddCost = 3,
            MulCost = 3
        };
    };
}  // namespace Eigen

//////////////////////
// TYPE DEFINITIONS //
//////////////////////

// GF 2
typedef Eigen::Matrix<GF2, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> GF2Matrix;

/////////////////
// SOLVE MOD 2 //
/////////////////

GF2Matrix solve_mod_2_GF2(GF2Matrix A, GF2Matrix b) {
    // https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html
    // householderQr is faster but yields incorrect results in some cases

    auto decomposition = A.fullPivLu();
    std::cout << "LU:" << std::endl << decomposition.matrixLU() << std::endl << std::endl;
    auto x = decomposition.solve(b);

    return x;
}

//////////
// MAIN //
//////////

int main () {
    int n = 5;

    GF2Matrix A(n, n);
    GF2Matrix b(n, 1);

    A << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
         0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
         1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
         1, 0, 0, 1, 1;
    b << 1, 0, 1, 0, 0;

    std::cout << "A:" << std::endl << A << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b:" << std::endl << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto x = solve_mod_2_GF2(A, b);

    std::cout << "x:" << std::endl << x << std::endl;

    // solution is incorrect, even though Ax=b admits solution
    // x = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

    return 0;
}
```

I am running my code like this (using eigen 3.4):

```sh
$ g++ -I./eigen -o my_solve.o -std=c++11 my_solve.cpp && ./my_solve.o 
A:
 1   0   0   0   1 
 0   1   0   0   0 
 1   0   1   1   0 
 0   0   0   1   1 
 1   0   0   1   1 

b:
 1 
 0 
 1 
 0 
 0 

LU:
 1   0   0   0   1 
 0   1   0   0   0 
 1   0   1   1   1 
 0   0   0   1   1 
 1   0   0   1   1 

x:
 1 
 0 
 0 
 1 
 1
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What's the result of `A.fullPivLu();`?

Comment: I added the result of `matrixLU` above

Comment: You are not implementing things like `operator+(GF2,GF2)`, so calling would actually implicitly convert to `bool` "add" two booleans which results in `int(2)` and implicitly convert that back to `GF2` (giving a `1` instead of a `0`). I would recommend making all conversions `explicit` and providing all necessary operators. You may also need to provide a custom `scalar_score_coeff_op` as described near the end of http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html

Comment: Also, be careful with `auto` and Eigen (your usage should be fine -- but it may be fragile to small changes ...)